# Child node not keeping same physicsBody when added to parent

Tags: sprite-kit

Using the Xcode SpriteKit Scene editor I have a few objects added to the scene as "obstacles." I like to animate them across the screen. They are not dynamic. To make things easier I thought to add them to an obstacleParent node and just animate that one object. The problem is that adding the obstacles to a parent totally screws up their physics bodies. Meaning the obstacle physics bodies do not match the outline of the sprite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it is a bug in the Scene editor, but adding the physics bodies programmatically yields results as expected.

Some interesting things worth noting are:

the physicsBodies moved with the parent regardless of if they were not Dynamic or not.

I could not get them to overlap each other until I made them all have the same contactTestBitMask

It is difficult to tell in the screen shot but all 3 children kept their physics shapes

If the parent has a physics body and an physics impulse is applied to it, only the parent moves. However setting the position of the parent programmatically moves the parent and child nodes[image]

```
    testObject = SKSpriteNode(texture: nil, color: .greenColor(), size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100))
    testObject.zPosition = Layer.Controls.rawValue
    testObject.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width / 2, y: self.size.height / 2)
//        testObject.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: testObject.width / 2)
//        testObject.physicsBody!.dynamic = true
//        testObject.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false
//        testObject.physicsBody!.allowsRotation = true
    addChild(testObject)

    let testerObject = SKSpriteNode(texture: nil, color: .clearColor(), size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100))
    testerObject.zPosition = Layer.Controls.rawValue
    testerObject.position = CGPoint(x:50, y: 50)

    testerObject.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: testerObject.width / 2)
    testerObject.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false
    testerObject.physicsBody!.dynamic = true
    testerObject.physicsBody!.allowsRotation = true
    testerObject.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = 0
    testerObject.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = 0

    testObject.addChild(testerObject)

    let testerObject2 = SKSpriteNode(texture: nil, color: .clearColor(), size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100))
    testerObject2.zPosition = Layer.Controls.rawValue
    testerObject2.position = CGPoint(x:-50, y: -50)

    testerObject2.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: testerObject.width / 2)
    testerObject2.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false
    testerObject2.physicsBody!.dynamic = true
    testerObject2.physicsBody!.allowsRotation = true
    testerObject2.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = 0
    testerObject2.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = 0
    testObject.addChild(testerObject2)

    let testerObject3 = SKSpriteNode(texture: nil, color: .clearColor(), size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100))
    testerObject3.zPosition = Layer.Controls.rawValue
    testerObject3.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: testerObject.width / 2)
    testerObject3.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false
    testerObject3.physicsBody!.dynamic = true
    testerObject3.physicsBody!.allowsRotation = true
    testerObject3.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = 0
    testerObject3.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = 0
    testObject.addChild(testerObject3)
```

Comment: I'm convinced it is a bug. Revisiting this after a while. The behavior is still there, but you are right.